# LDAP search returning unexpected object type

Tags: ldap, jndi, tivoli

I am issuing a LDAP query against an IBM Tivoli Directory Server (I am querying for the special user "cn=monitor", but I don't know if that is significant).

I execute the following code:
   DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
   Object o = ctx.lookup ("cn=monitor");

I was expecting o to be of type NamingEnumeration, but instead it is of type DirContext. I can't figure out how to get the returned data from this object type.

Strangely enough, I can see that the data I want is being fetched because I set debugging on with the following command:
   env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.trace.ber", System.out);

Answer (score 0):

> I was expecting o to be of type NamingEnumeration, but instead it is of type DirContext.

Why? `NamingEnumerations` are returned by the `search()` method. Not by the `lookup()` methods. There's nothing in the documentation to suggest otherwise.

Comment: I tried using search(), but it didn't work for me. If lookup() doesn't  return NamingEnumerations, how can I parse through the data it fetched from the server?

Comment: You don't have to 'parse through the data'. It is a single object representing the unique entry by that name.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I should be using search() instead of lookup().

I tried search() before, but it was failing due to incorrect scope setting. I fixed this and now my code is working,

Comment: You should use `search()` if you expect multiple results, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In case if will be helpful, example code:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://XXX");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "DOMAIN\\user.name"); 
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            if(ctx != null){
               String []requiredAttributes = {"sn","cn","sAMAccountName","memberOf"};
               SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
               controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
               controls.setReturningAttributes(requiredAttributes);
               SearchResult searchResult = null;
               NamingEnumeration user = ctx.search(USER_SEARCH_BASE, USER_SEARCH_FILTER, controls);
    while(users.hasMore()){
                searchResult=(SearchResult)users.next();
                Attributes attr = searchResult.getAttributes();
                String commonName = attr.get("cn").get(0).toString();
                System.out.println("Common Name: " + commonName);
               }

            }
```